# Restart-Service output to file

Tags: windows, powershell, server

Using Task Scheduler I am running a PS script to restart selected Windows Services using **Restart-Service**. For troubleshooting issues I'd like to write the output to a log file so we can make sure the service did restart. For the life of me I can't get the output file to write anything just creates the file in date format, but no contents. 
THank you

Edit:
OG Script

```
Restart-Service Printer Spooler -Force | Out-File c:\scripts\test3.txt
```

If I add *-PassThru* I get an output but the output is pretty bare bones. Would like to log steps of the Service Controller.

```
Restart-Service Printer Spooler -Force -PassThru | Out-File c:\scripts\test3.txt
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code. Also show the configuration of the scheduled task.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to include your code for anyone to offer help. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `Restart-Service` doesn't output anything, you'll need to provide the `-PassThru` parameter switch for it to do so

Comment: Ugh, service cmdlets don't interact with services as reliably as I'd like so you're probably better off writing your own. Test initial status, use start/stop as required, attempt to start, test status again, loop as required. Can output what you like at the various statuses.

Comment: You could use `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` to at least get a log of your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$logFile = "C:\Windows\Temp\out.txt"
$serviceName = "serviceName"

Restart-Service $serviceName -Verbose *> $logFile
```

The `-Verbose` switch gives you detailed start/stop attempt information

`*>` Redirects all command output to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the service you're restarting talks to the eventlogs, I'd grab the data from there and log it. Or leave it in there and grab it as needed. If you want to output it, this is one approach:

```
$date = (get-date).AddMinutes(-5)
$serviceData = Get-Service wersvc 
restart-service $serviceData
$eventData = Get-Winevent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = 'System'; StartTime = $date; ID = 7036} | ? {$_.message -match $serviceData.DisplayName}
$eventData | Out-File C:\logs\filename.txt
```